# Flex with PHP Deployment

Tags: php, apache-flex, windows-installer, web-deployment

I'm working on FLEX web app project using php as the data access. I was wondering if there was a packaging tool for deployment. In .NET there is the "Setup and Deployment" tool for ASP and others. But the big problems here is, i use a map that gets it's authentication key based on the IP address or domain name of the server installing the application.

Any feedback regarding this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution for your problem is to inject the map key from your PHP back-end into the client as the back-end is supposed to know where it runs.

As for the packaging tool, I personally use [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/), it allows you to compile Flex files (via flexTasks.jar provided by the Flex SDK) and PHP packaging is usually just copying/moving files around, I don't think you need more for the packaging part for both Flex and PHP.

Hope that helps.